# $G$-invariant operators on $L^2(G)$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, operator-theory, lie-groups, operator-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group equipped with a left-invariant Haar measure. Then elements of $G$ act as bounded operators on $L^2(G)$, with action given by translation:

$$(g\cdot f)(h):=f(g^{-1}h),$$

for any $f\in L^2(G)$, $g,h\in G$.

Let us say that an operator $T\in\mathcal{B}(L^2(G))$ is $G$-invariant if

$$g\circ T\circ g^{-1} = T$$

for all $g\in G$. One can check that, for example, convolution by a function in $C_c(G)$ is $G$-invariant.

**Question:** does every $G$-invariant operator in $\mathcal{B}(L^2(G))$ arise as the limit of a sequence of elements of $C_c(G)$ acting by convolution?

In other words, are the $G$-invariant operators in $\mathcal{B}(L^2(G))$ precisely the elements of the reduced group $C^*$-algebra $C^*_\lambda(G)$?

Comment: The set of $G$-invariant operators is the commutant of the set of left translation operators, and hence, by Von Neumann's bicommutant theorem, is actually a von Neumann algebra containing the right regular representation of $C^\ast_\lambda(G)$. In particular, it is necessarily unital, but $C^\ast_\lambda(G)$ is unital if and only if $G$ is discrete. Now it shouldn't be too hard to see that this von Neumann algebra exactly coincides with $C^\ast_\lambda(G)$ if and only if $G$ is finite—otherwise, the von Neumann algebra generated by $C^\ast_\lambda(G)$ will be strictly larger.